# Sentinel-2: Resampling Spatial Resolution

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing

Does resampling spatial resolution possible to do for all of the Sentinel-2 products, especially Level-1C? For instance, I want to uniform **B1 - B12** spatial resolution to **20m**. I just want to confirm it in terms of theory.

Could you share a reference for this topic?

Answer (score 0):

That is possible. Here are two links explaining the details of how scale and resampling work in Earth Engine:

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/resample

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/scale